# Button not refreshing on going different window form

Tags: winapi, button, window, buttonclick

I had created buttons on a dialog using resource editor(using Visual C++,X64) . On the button click  event i have to show another window which is exactly of the same size and at same place (For further details i want to tell you that i have two buttons "next" and "previous" . on clicking them i have preview of "Image" and a "File" respectively). My dialog uses the handle of parent which comes from GetWindow function. See this please -

```
   SomeClassOrFounctionNoMatterWhat::GetWindow(HWND *phwnd)
    {
        HRESULT hr = E_INVALIDARG;
        if (phwnd)
        {
            *phwnd = m_hwndParent; //m_hwndParent is the parent handle now
            hr = S_OK;
        }
        return hr;
    }
```

So i mean the parent handle is m_hwndParent and using this handle i have created Dialog using this-

```
m_hwndPreview = CreateDialogParam(g_hInst
                                  MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_MAINDIALOG),
                                  m_hwndParent,
                                  (DLGPROC)DialogProc,
                                  (LPARAM)this);
```

and `m_hwndPreview` contains the button which i have created on the dialog `IDD_MAINDIALOG`.
and on button click event i am displaying the a file contents like this-

```
m_hwndPreview3 = CreateWindowExW(0,
                                 MSFTEDIT_CLASS,
                                 NULL, //This window is to display the html file.
                                 WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_VSCROLL|ES_MULTILINE|ES_READONLY|WS_EX_TOPMOST,
                                 m_rcParent.left, m_rcParent.top,
                                 RECTWIDTH(m_rcParent),RECTHEIGHT(m_rcParent),
                                 m_hwndPreview,
                                 NULL,
                                 NULL,
                                 NULL);  // similarly m_hwndPreview2 for image preview
```

See I am using m_hwndPreview as its parent which contains the buttons. I am doing so because i want to have buttons on my every window in order to display different contents by clicking on them.

So my problem is the buttons are created succesfully and are working properly but when i click any button  it takes me on different window for the display of the file or Image. But when it takes me on different window the button disappears on the first sight and they appears only when i move mouse over them.

**What should i do in order to have the button appearing on every window without moving mouse over them ?**

Comment: Sounds like you're reinventing wizards. [How to Create Wizards](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774544.aspx) beat you to it.

Comment: Also, in your call to [`CreateWindowEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680.aspx) you are mixing [window styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600.aspx) and [extended window styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543.aspx).

Comment: @Tim thanks but please make it clear to me in simple language what should i do to refresh my buttons so that it will appear on every window without hovering mouse over them ? please.

Comment: You could probably call [`UpdateWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145167.aspx) to have the controls update. My suggestion is still this: If you implement something that looks like a wizard, and behaves like a wizard, your best bet would be to use a wizard. Individual pages in a [Property Sheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774540.aspx) can be constructed from dialog resources just as well.

Comment: One more note: You should not have to cast the `lpDialogFunc` parameter in your call to `CreateDialogParam`. If you got the signature wrong, or the calling convention, the compiler will inform you about this. Unless you use a cast.

Comment: @IInspectable if i use UpadateWindow(m_hwndPreview);  to update the buttons(m_hwndPreview because it contains the handle of button). but still its the same problem.And about implementing through wizard. How to do that? i have to display an image and a html file contents on the window on the different button clicks. Is it possible to create a window inside the wizard in order to have the image and file preview and button also  ? please f=give any link if you have to give me idea about that. Thanks

Comment: My first and fourth comment provide links to the documentation. A wizard is the same as a property sheet, except that arbitrary navigation between individual tabs is replaced with sequential navigation through wizard buttons. A property page can host arbitrary controls. If you are looking to see a property sheet in action, right-click a file and select *Properties*. A well known example of a wizard is the standard MSI Installer.